# JNI load .so file compiled with c++11 arise error “/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found”

Tags: java, c++11, java-native-interface

I compiled C++ code with gcc 4.8.2 (which is c++11 version and it is necessary for my C++ code) and generated a `libmy.so` file. I want to call the method in `libmy.so` from Java code with JNI, and I have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be the path of `libmy.so`. When run Java code, errors info is like below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   .../libmy.so: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not
>   found (required by libmy.so)

Because this Linux machine is common used, I don't want to modify files in /usr/lib64 (e.g., modify the link of `libstdc++.so.6`).

By the way, my JDK version is 1.8, I tried JDK 1.11 and it also failed.

It seems that Java can't load the right version of `libstdc++.so.6` (also for `libc.so`), but I am not sure.

How to fix this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Um: it loads your libmy.so as it is in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Thats fine. But libmy in turn needs a c++ lib of a specific version you used to compile it:  "GLIBCXX_3.4.18". That c++ library is not found. Now you can put that lib also in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and it might work(I say might as Java is also compiled against c++ and a lib conflict may occur)

Comment: yes, it also failed.  i tried to put "/opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib64" in my LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and there are “libc.so.6” & “libstdc++.so.6” in "/opt/compiler/gcc-4.8.2/lib64". But it arise "segmentation fault"...

Comment: now a segmentation fault instead? Compile with symbols and look at the coredump. That may be a Nullpinter in your lib. But in general: why not compile against a c++ lib, that is available(meaning: can be made available) on your system: See it is idea of a shared lib(so) to be able to share it. Thats the whole point in having them instead of static linking(which gives faster code, with smaler footprint and needs no runtime loading logic). 'But the latter only as a sidenode. For the Segmentation fault look at the BT.